# LF RFID chip with protocol select

Tags: rfid

Is there any RFID reader IC wherein I can select what protocols I want to read in a band ? Any kind of help would be useful.

Comment: LF = looking for?

Comment: @JYelton , Low Frequency. I.E. 125Khz. The RFIDs are categorized by LF(125Khz), HF(13.56Mhz), UHF(~900Mhz). Though you can take it as Looking For, cause that is what am doing.

Answer (score 1):

We are using [this module](http://www.elatec-rfid.com/web/10583/36) in one of our projects and so far i can really recommend it.

[EDIT]
I did not notice the low frequency requirement and the proposed reader is using 13.56MHz. But the same company has [some 125kHz](http://www.elatec-rfid.com/web/10583/19) readers as well, those may have similar options to exclude specific transponder types. Depending on the requirements, it could also be an option to "filter" specific reader types in software as soon as a tag is detected.
[/EDIT]

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you can configure the module to exclude specific transponder types from the transponder search.

> Don’t search for ISO14443A transponders
>   Don’t search for ISO14443B transponders
>   Don’t search for PicoPass / ICLASS transponders
>   Don’t search for SRX transponders
>   Don’t search for ISO15693 transponders

FYI, the following transponder types are supported:

> 00  Mifare® Mini
>   01  Mifare® Classic 1K
>   02  Mifare® Classic 4K
>   03  Mifare® Plus S
>   04  Mifare® Plus X
>   05  Mifare® Ultralight / Ultralight C
>   06  Mifare® DESFire
>   0F  Unknown ISO14443A transponder
>   10  I•Code SL2
>   11  I•Code SL2-S
>   12  Tag-it™ HF-I Plus Inlay
>   13  Tag-it™ HF-I Plus Chip
>   14  Tag-it™ HF-I Standard
>   15  Tag-it™ HF-I Pro
>   16  ST 24LR16 Dual Interface EEPROM
>   17  ST 24LR64 Dual Interface EEPROM
>   18  Fujitsu MB89R118
>   19  Fujitsu MB89R119
>   1F  Unknown ISO15693 transponder
>   30  Picopass / ICLASS transponder
>   40  SRX transponder
>   80  ISO14443B transponder

Following my link, there is a PDF with technical specifications available, but you have to contact their support for the extensive technical handbook.

Comment: But it doesn't support 125Khz LF i guess. Still I will look into it. But the only hurdle that I can see is, RFID Tag cost. Plus I need the range atleast a meter.

Comment: Oh, i did not notice the "Low Frequency" prefix in the title. And as far as i know, the standards that my proposed reader supports can't transmit as far as 1m. However, the company has similar modules using 125kHZ. May its worth a closer look.